# escaping strings to store in database and print in html

Tags: php, escaping, mysql-real-escape-string, htmlspecialchars

I want to know if there is a way to simply take the input of a user, apply `mysqli_real_escape_string()` and `htmlspecialchars()`, store in a database, and print to the screen as the exact same thing the user inputted?

Can i just run both of these on a string, or should it be in a certain order, or is there another way I should be handling this? Thanks to anyone in advance.

Comment: You definitely want to use `mysqli_real_escape_string()` to sanitize your database input. I recommend only applying `htmlspecialchars()` at the moment you are generating HTML, as you may find down the road you want to use your database-stored text in some other context (e.g. JavaScript, CSV, or whatever), where HTML entities are not ideal.

Comment: even if im storing the data in a database? what about mysql injection?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mention that part because I thought it was a given. I edited my comment to be more clear.

Comment: so what your saying is create two variables with the same value, apply mysqli_real_escape_string() to one and store that in the databas, and toke the other and use htmlspecialchars()?

Comment: Umm... well I don't know the context of your code. That's one way, or you can just call these functions on the same variable in the appropriate places. Whatever suits your need.

Comment: ok, thanks, that's kind of what i was asking, but thanks, i will just apply them both.

Answer (score 0):

If you use prepared statements, you do not need `mysqli_real_escape_string()`.
So you can store the exact userinput in your database.

To output the exact user input, you will have to use `htmlspecialchars()` just before you print i out. Otherwise you will lose inputs like `<`, as it is interpreted as (invalid) HTML.